# how to run custom action type flow in system context from a community?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, customer-portal

I have created a custom action with action type "flow". This flow has been configured to run in system context. When I log in to my community and I click on this custom action button, the flow does not seem to run in system context. So, how do you get a portal user to execute code or a flow in system context from custom action button?

[image: custom action type flow]

[image]